# Adding more fuel to your gas tank than it can hold

Tags: java

I am working on a car program that can hold more fuel that can hold and also the output does show 0 and not a negative number. I have the code completed but Im required to modify the drive() and refuel() method as shown its my Car.java:

```
public class Car { 
int year;
String make;
String model;
double mileage;
double fuelLevel;
double maxFuel;
double mpg;

//add a contructor here
//make sure you add a defult constructor

public Car () {

}

public Car(int yr, String mk, String mdl) {
  year = yr;
  make = mk;
  model = mdl;
}

public String toString() {
  String retString = "";
  retString += year + " " + make + " " + model;
  retString += "\n" + mileage + " mi";
  retString += "\n" + fuelLevel + " gal remaining";
  return retString;
}

public void drive(double distance) {
  mileage = mileage + distance;
  fuelLevel = fuelLevel - distance / mpg;

}

public void reFuel(double gasInGal) {
  fuelLevel += gasInGal;
  }
}
```

Here is my Main.Java file:

```
public class Main
        public static void main(String[] args) {
      Car car1 = new Car ();
      car1.year = 2001;
      car1.make = "Toyota";
      car1.model = "Camery";
      car1.mileage = 156000;
      car1.fuelLevel = 6.0;
      car1.maxFuel = 12.5;
      car1.mpg = 32.3;

      Car car2 = new Car();
      car2.year = 2020;
      car2.make = "Ferrari";
      car2.model = "309";
      car2.mileage = 20.3;
      car2.fuelLevel = 15.0;
      car2.maxFuel = 22.0;
      car2.mpg = 12.2;

      System.out.println("Creating instance of two cars");
      System.out.println(car1);
      System.out.println("\n" + car2);

      //baby you can drive my car
      System.out.println("Car driving:");
      car1.drive(50);
      car2.drive(5);

      System.out.println("\nDriving Car");
      System.out.println("\n " + car1);
      System.out.println("\n " + car2);

      //beep beep beep beep yeah
      car1.reFuel(12.9);
      car2.reFuel(12);

      System.out.println("\n " + car1);
      System.out.println("\n " + car2);

      }
    }
```

I need to add more fuel to your gas tank than it can hold, I need to make sure the fuelLevel is not more than the maxFuel. And if I try to drive longer than you have enough gas (fuelRemaining * mpg) you need to only drive that distance and then set your fuel to 0, not a negative number.

I am asking kindly on how to start not giving me the answer; I want to learn and understand! :)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you clarify what your question actually is? Eg. For the refueling problem, can you show how you attempted to solve the problem (eg compare amount + refuel amount to max, etc.) and then explain what you are having issue with?

Comment: I'm sorry if the question is confusing but I'm trying to find if my car will keep driving after I use all the fuel and if I can put more gas in the car than the size of the gas tank.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. But your `refuel` method doesn't seem like it attempts to solve that problem: it just takes the new amount and adds it to the existing amount; nowhere does it check that it has exceeded the max limit. If you show us how you attempt to solve it and explain what's going wrong, we can help you figure it out.

Comment: I need to add more fuel to your gas tank than it can hold, I need to make sure the fuelLevel is not more than the maxFuel. - isn't that already contradicting?

Comment: @NightCode, you described what you are doing, but you did not actually ask a question